# Is there an alternative to ImageMapster that works with jQuery 3.x?

Tags: jquery, imagemapster, jquery-3

I've been trying all afternoon to get ImageMapster to work...  I kept getting the weirdest errors, and all the Google searching in the world didn't help...  (Stuff like "Uncaught TypeError: i.size is not a function".  What the heck does that even mean?!)

Turns out, I was using jQuery 3.4.1 and ImageMapster isn't compatible with that.  I switched to jQuery 2.2.4, and it finally seems to be working.  Like, literally the exact same code, only with the `<script>` tag source switched from 3.4.1 to 2.2.4, and all my problems go away.  Ridiculous.

Problem is, this has to go into a Cordova app where we're using jQuery 3.x

So...  How do I get something with the functionality of ImageMapster, but will work with jQuery 3.x?  Basically, I need to programmatically highlight areas of a `<map>` in JavaScript.  So any ideas on how to do that other than with ImageMapster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [this fork](https://github.com/jamietre/imagemapster) of ImageMapster.

Version 1.3.0 works with jQuery version 3.5.1.